# Django model manager using foreign models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Can I make a manager in django to return queries from another model?
This is for django 2 with python 3.4. Possibly a newbie problem.

Say I have two models, one with foreign key to another:

```
    class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    class Car(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='driver')
    name = models.CharField()
```

I want to have a manger for Person that gives all cars that has a given "Person" as a driver. I can think of some workarounds, but it feels like django default manager should allow that.

My idea was to prepare a manger for Person that returns hard-coded queries of Car, but it is impossible because names of classess can't be resolved (Person needs to know the body of a manager, and a manager needs to know the body of a Car).

Comment: From your question, what I understand is, using `person_instance` if you want to get all the `Car` objects, you can go with `person_instance.driver.all()`. Also, `related_name` should be plural, as it returns list of objects.

Comment: Yes, you don't need a Manager, as Tanmay says this functionality is built in.

Comment: Thank you. So easy.